# How to proceed Stripe payment directly in the PHP backend?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, backend, payment

My client has an online store using Stripe as a payment method. The online store is 100% custom (no WordPress/Shopify/Magento/Lavarel/React) - only PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS, and JS.

Firstly, I integrate for him Stripe Checkout API which after clicking the "Pay now" button redirects you to a stripe checkout page to fill in your name, email, and card details. After success, it returns the customer back to the store's "successful payment" page.

But my client realized he wants to optimize the process and NOT to redirect payment to the external (stripe's) page.
So I decide to use Stripe Elements which are integrated directly into the store's checkout page.

He was okay with this way for a few months but now wants to be even more optimized. So we had a three-step checkout and now merge it into just one.

And my question is:

- IS IT POSSIBLE when you are on the checkout page and fill in the credit card details (custom form NOT stripe's one) and click on the "Finalise" button - to create and process the payment in the backend (PHP) and to return success message via AJAX.
- I have now credit card details (WE ARE NOT STORING THEM) in the backend but I can't find the way how to create and process payment with them.
- I found how to create a PaymentMethod object:

  ```
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
        'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'
    );
    $stripe->paymentMethods->create([
        'type' => 'card',
        'card' => [
            'number' => '4242424242424242',
            'exp_month' => 8,
            'exp_year' => 2023,
            'cvc' => '314',
        ],
    ]);
  ```
- This returns me a PaymentMethod object. I found also out how to create a Customer object. But now I can't find any example of how to implement and process payment with this PaymentMethod object (which holds the customer card details). Is it possible at all or I am trying something simply impossible?

P.S.: I was also looking at Stripe's Payment Intents API, but not sure it's what I need in this case...

```
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
        'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'
    );
    $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'amount' => 2000,
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
    ]);
```

I have an idea of first creating Customer object, then creating Card object to this Customer ID, then creating Charge object with "source" => the Card ID, and then check the return if the charge succeeded.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it necessary to Create a card token instead of creating Card object? Because in Stripe's documentation there are using tokens for value of "source" => "token_here" in Charge API? And is it Charge API that what I am looking for at all?

Comment: Seems like this would be a question to ask Stripe? Payment gateways can be a real chore in my experience. Stripe offers [SDKs](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries) for various programming languages, but there's always a lot of particulars to slog through.

Comment: Do you have the required [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide) to be handling PAN data directly in your integration? I suspect not, in which case you should absolutely not be integrating this way. Instead, use Elements or Checkout.